# Proteção do APK contra disassembly e outros

Tags: android

Gostaria de saber, quais as formas de se proteger o código de um `APK Android`, pois se extrairmos, temos os templates, se usar certos programas, temos praticamente todas as `classes`.

Quais formas conhecem para proteção contra isso ?

Gostaria de REPOSTA SÓLIDAS COM EXEMPLOS ou links úteis, pois o conceito em si, encontrei alguns, mas gostaria de saber da comunidade BR.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854425/how-to-avoid-reverse-engineering-of-an-apk-file

Comment: Rafael, eu vi que você editou, queria saber o motivo melhor para eu não errar nas próximas perguntas :)

Sobre o link, eu vi exatamente ele, mas estão passando muito superficialmente, tanto o mais votado, quanto o segundo mais votado.
Queria saber mais especificamente como seria ofuscar os códigos das classes, onde poderia dar uma olhada para ter uma noção inicial entende ?

Comment: Tente destacar os pontos importantes da sua pergunta, para ficar melhor formatado.

Comment: Em resumo, não da para evitar, é basicamente `impossivel`, o que da pra fazer, é o que foi dito, `ofuscar`, basicamente, dificultar. Ex: `minificar` um arquivo `JS` é um meio de dificultar que liam nosso `JS` (não que seja 100% eficaz, pois existe sites que desminificam). É basicamente isso, existe milhares de forma de dificultar, mas nenhuma que ira resolver de verdade o problema.

Comment: Nossa cara que zica ! Basicamente toda parte "bruta" que faria o "diferencial" do app ficaria no `webservice` já que não tem como !
Obrigado Rafael !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toda a parte bruta fica no back, o legal é usar `Token` para validar sessões com o Back-End para se protejer.

Como tinha dito, o importante é tratar bem o back-end para evitar serios problemas futuros, da uma lida nesse [conteudo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token).

Vale lembrar, que o app em si, não passa de `Front`, `elementos`, `animações` e etc. Assim como uma pagina `WEB`.

Todos passam por esses problemas, mas se for o caso `minifique` seus arquivos, e até mesmo `ofusque` um pouco, se isso lhe incomoda, não há problema algum em dificultar o trabalho de pessoas mal intencionados.